# Triggering workflow based upon Bulk Data Update

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

We have a SharePoint custom list named "Price List" with Customer Code and Products related to each customer

e.g.
[image]

I need to trigger the sharepoint workflow only once whenever 1 or multiple product  related to single customer is updated /created /deleted .

Kindly help me in this issue . Any advice or suggestion will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: helped this to you?

Answer (score 0):

There is not any option with doing this in this list, but i have an idea.

- Create another list with All unique customers "Customers" with columns "Customer name" and "Change before" (NUMBER starts with 0)
- Create workflow in "Price List" list create WF which will be run on create/change, where you will update in "Customers" list record where Customer name is the same as "Product name" in "Price List", you will increment "Change before",
- In "Customer" list create another workflow which will be trigered on item change and here will be your actions.

Workflow can run only one instance per item (if there is newest version)